# Oracle: Why does to_date() accept 2 digit year when I have 4 digits in format string? - and how to enforce 4 digits?

Tags: oracle

I want to check a date for correctness. (Let's not talk about the fact, that the date is stored in a varchar please ...)

Dates are stored like DDMMYYYY so for instance 24031950 is a correct date. 240319 is not.

So I do this, when the call works, it's a correct date:

```
select to_date('24031950','DDMMYYYY') from dual;
```

But unfortunately this also does not return an error:

```
select to_date('240319','DDMMYYYY') from dual (why?);
```

But it's interesting, that this one does not work:

```
select to_date('190324','YYYYMMDD') from dual;
```

So, how to enforce a check o 4 digit year with the given format mask?

Thanks!

Comment: `select to_date('240319','DDMMYYYY')` returns `24 March 19 A.D.` (note `19`, not `2019` or `1919`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212):

> Oracle Database converts strings to dates with some flexibility. [...]

And I believe that flexibility is what you are seeing. You can turn it off with the `fx` modifier:

> `FX`: Requires exact matching between the character data and the format model

```
select to_date('240319','fxDDMMYYYY') from dual;
```

Gives an ORA-01862 error.

Answer (score 4):

Just an additional note to Mat's answer. `fx` acts like a switch in the string.

For example `TO_DATE('2019-11-5','fxYYYY-MM-DD')` gives an ORA-01862 error because exact matching applies for the entire string. If you need exact match only for parts of the string, then use for example

```
TO_DATE('2019-11-5','fxYYYY-MM-fxDD')
```

In this case `YYYY-MM-` has to match exactly, whereas `DD` applies flexible (or lazy) match.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether it is in correct format without exceptions you can also use regex functions. 
One possible way would to be check if the string contains 8 digits:

```
select REGEXP_INSTR  ('24031950', '[0-9]{8}') from dual;
1


select REGEXP_INSTR  ('240350', '[0-9]{8}') from dual;
0
```